# DataTable.Select SQL injection protection needed?

Tags: c#, .net, database, vb.net

I 'd like to enable the user to apply a custom filter to a System.Data.DataTable.
At the moment I have a very simple function like this:

```
   Dim result = dataTable.Select(txtUserInput.Text)
```

With the filtered results I'd like to do further operations(e.g. Database Update/Delete).

Is an sql injection protection needed or is the "Select" function secure?

Thank you

**//Edit:**
The main question is: Can the "select" function be abused to manipulate any data in the datatable, execute code, ...? If the only danger is that this function can return to much/to less data there is no problem. But if the data in the dataset gets corrupted it's a real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need protection in that instance - DataTable.Select is applying a filter to the DataRows held in-memory within that DataTable, it's not actually connecting to/executing anything against the database.

You would need protection if you were taking that user input and building it into a SQL statement you then execute against the db to e.g. initially fill the DataTable. In that case, best thing is to parameterise the statement.

Comment: thought he want to do some updates e.g. with the filtered stuff, so protection is needed

Comment: The main question is: Can the "select" function be abused to manipulate any data in the datatable, execute code, ...? If the only danger is that this function can return to much/to less data there is no problem. But if the data in the dataset gets corrupted it's a real problem.

Comment: @Mimefilt you can select your injection string into a cell. when you use this cell afterwards to do an update it can ends badly. So i think its ok to generally add protection against it.

Comment: @AdaTheDev how to parameterise the data in the `Datatable.Select`  , I mean how to `SqlParameter(key,value)` in the `Datatable.Select`

Answer (score 0):

Match only alphanumeric characters along with the characters -, +, .,<,>,=,! and any whitespace

Comment: Oh, great, another of those totally arbitrary limitations. "Sorry, you cannot limit to rows containing '?'." And when you think of that, you run full speed into what constitutes alphanumeric characters in an international and multilingual world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql parameters, or switch to LINQ to SQL, it protect the inject attack for you.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE dummy (@x AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS EXEC 'UPDATE mytable SET column=something WHERE othercolumn=''' + @x + '''';` (To illustrate the point, not necessarily be exactly correct in any particular RDBMS.) Parameters are *not* a panacea; non-parameterized, even dynamic, SQL *can* be safe, and parameterized SQL *can* be vulnerable to injection attacks. While it's easier to write safe parameterized code, it really is all about how you write the SQL, not whether or not you use query parameters.